# onClick get form details and send email

Tags: javascript, php, forms, onclick

I have a form with after closing form tag an a link.
I want to get the form input and have send them to my e-mail when clicking the link. When clicked the user should stay on the same page but hiding the form.
This is my (simplified) markup:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function doSomething() {
   $.get("sendform.php");
   return false;
  }
</script>

<form id="myForm">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name"first name"><br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname">
</form>
<a href="#" onClick="doSomething();">Send</a>
```

Can I use the $.post() method? And if I can, how would I do this?

Comment: Yes you can, have you looked at the `$.post` api documentation and tried to use it?

Answer (score 0):

1. Get form data.
2. Prepare ajax post(url,sendData,callback).
3. Hide form.
4. (Optional) Do some action after successful submit.

   ```js
   function doSomething() {
       var form = $('#myForm');
       var formdata = form.serialize();// 1
       $.post("sendform.php",formdata, function(data){ //2
           //here you can do different action after make you post request //4
       });
       form.hide(); //3
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <form id="myForm">
     First name:<br>
     <input type="text" name="first_name"><br>
     Last name:<br>
     <input type="text" name="lastname">
   </form>
   <a href="#" onClick="doSomething();">Send</a>
   ```

Comment: Please don't just dump code as an answer. This teaches nothing, explains nothing, and just lets OP know they don't have to try and people will do it for them.

Comment: @SterlingArcher ok. I'll give you discribe

Comment: This gives me a TypeError $ is not a function

Comment: Are you include jQuery on your site? `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: @PavloZhukov it was, now he gives an error ReferenceError: doSomething is not defined. (onclick)

Comment: @CliffVandyck maybe you difined `doSomething` into anonymuous function?

Comment: @CliffVandyck Braces are exceeded

Comment: @PavloZhukov Error now occurring: SyntaxError: missing ( before formal parameters

Comment: @CliffVandyck sorry, time go to bed. Return the brace.

Comment: @CliffVandyck where you define function? If in a global scope you must have access to use it

Comment: @PavloZhukov I put my full code in an answer, can you check this?

Comment: @CliffVandyck I fix them. Function, defined in anonymuos function, isn't visible from html

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery and Ajax. Here is a sample code. I did not test this code but the logic should be similar:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#myButton").click(function(){
        $.ajax({url: "sendform.php", success: function(result){
            $("#divResult").html(result);
        }});
    });
</script>

<form id="myForm">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name"first name"><br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname">
</form>
<a id="#myButton" href="#" >Send</a>
<div id="divResult"></div>
```

Here is some good documentation on how to use jQuery's $.ajax() function: https://www.sitepoint.com/use-jquerys-ajax-function/  Hope this helps.

Comment: You miss send form data.

Comment: This just sends me to the top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Include jQuery right after opening `<body>` tag:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This is what my full code looks like now (some things are irrelevant):

```
(function($) {

$(".em-booking-form").attr('id', 'werkgever-form');

$('#masterclasses_repertoire').attr('placeholder','(max. 2000 tekens)');
$('#masterclasses_biografie').attr('placeholder','(max. 2000 tekens)');
$('#masterclasses_motivatie').attr('placeholder','(max. 2000 tekens)');
$('#masterclasses_opmerkingen').attr('placeholder','(specifieke dieetbehoeften)');

$(".em-attendee-fieldset").insertAfter($(".input-field-workshop_opmerkingen"));
$(".em-attendee-fieldset").insertAfter($(".input-field-master_final_opmerkingen"));
$(".em-attendee-fieldset").insertAfter($(".input-field-master_passief_opmerkingen"));

$(".facturatiegegevens, .input-field-workshop_gelijk_adres, .input-field-factuur_bedrijf, .input-field-factuur_naam_contactpersoon, .input-field-factuur_email_contactpersoon, .input-field-factuur_straat, .input-field-factuur_nummer, .input-field-factuur_bus, .input-field-factuur_postcode, .input-field-factuur_gemeente, .input-field-factuur_land, .input-field-factuur_btw-nummer, .input-field-factuur_opmerkingen").wrapAll("<div class='kader'></div>");

$(".postid-4465 .aanmelden").prop("value", "Aanmelden");

$('input[value="Ik heb geen factuur nodig."]').attr('checked',true);



$('.input-field-workshop_akkoord').after('<a id="werkgever-button" class="btn btn-primary" href="#" onClick="doSomething()">Reservering versturen</button>');

$(".em-booking-gateway").css('display', 'block');

$("input[name='workshop_wenst_u_een_factuur']").click(function () {
$('.facturatiegegevens').css('display', ($(this).val() === 'Ik heb geen factuur nodig.') ? 'none':'block'),
$('.kader').css('display', ($(this).val() === 'Ik heb geen factuur nodig.') ? 'none':'block'),
$('.em-booking-gateway').css('display', ($(this).val() === 'Mijn werkgever zal betalen.') ? 'none':'block'),
$('.em-booking-buttons').css('display', ($(this).val() === 'Mijn werkgever zal betalen.') ? 'none':'block'),
$('#werkgever-button').css('display', ($(this).val() === 'Mijn werkgever zal betalen.') ? 'block' : 'none'),
$('.input-field-workshop_gelijk_adres').css('display', ($(this).val() === 'Ik heb wel een factuur nodig.') ? 'block':'none'),
$('.input-field-factuur_bedrijf').css('display', ($(this).val() === 'Ik heb geen factuur nodig.') ? 'none':'block'),
$('.input-field-factuur_naam_contactpersoon').css('display', ($(this).val() === 'Ik heb geen factuur nodig.') ? 'none':'block'),
$('.input-field-factuur_email_contactpersoon').css('display', ($(this).val() === 'Ik heb geen factuur nodig.') ? 'none':'block'),
$('.input-field-factuur_straat').css('display', ($(this).val() === 'Ik heb geen factuur nodig.') ? 'none':'block'),
$('.input-field-factuur_nummer').css('display', ($(this).val() === 'Ik heb geen factuur nodig.') ? 'none':'block'),
$('.input-field-factuur_bus').css('display', ($(this).val() === 'Ik heb geen factuur nodig.') ? 'none':'block'),
$('.input-field-factuur_postcode').css('display', ($(this).val() === 'Ik heb geen factuur nodig.') ? 'none':'block'),
$('.input-field-factuur_gemeente').css('display', ($(this).val() === 'Ik heb geen factuur nodig.') ? 'none':'block'),
$('.input-field-factuur_land').css('display', ($(this).val() === 'Ik heb geen factuur nodig.') ? 'none':'block'),
$('.input-field-factuur_btw-nummer').css('display', ($(this).val() === 'Ik heb geen factuur nodig.') ? 'none':'block'),
$('.input-field-factuur_opmerkingen').css('display', ($(this).val() === 'Ik heb geen factuur nodig.') ? 'none':'block');
})

$("#workshop_gelijk_adres").change(function() {
  if(this.checked) {
    //get the values of the filled fields
    $naam = $("#workshop_naam").val();
    $email = $("#user_email").val();
    $straat = $("#workshop_straat").val();
    $nummer = $("#workshop_nummer").val();
    $bus = $("#workshop_bus").val();
    $postcode = $("#workshop_postcode").val();
    $gemeente = $("#workshop_gemeente").val();
    $land = $("select.workshop_land").val();
    console.log("name");
    // then add those values to your billing infor window feilds 

    $("#factuur_naam_contactpersoon").val($naam);
    $("#factuur_email_contactpersoon").val($email);
    $("#factuur_straat").val($straat);
    $("#factuur_nummer").val($nummer);
    $("#factuur_bus").val($bus);
    $("#factuur_postcode").val($postcode);
    $("#factuur_gemeente").val($gemeente);
    $("select.factuur_land").val($land);

    // then form will be automatically filled .. 
  }
  else {
    $('#factuur_naam_contactpersoon').val('');
    $("#factuur_email_contactpersoon").val('');
    $("#factuur_straat").val('');
    $("#factuur_nummer").val('');
    $("#factuur_bus").val('');
    $("#factuur_postcode").val('');
    $("#factuur_gemeente").val('');
    $("select.factuur_land").val('');
  }
})

})(jQuery);

function doSomething() {
    var form = $('#myForm');
    var formdata = form.serialize();// 1
    $.post("http://www.lowie-design.be/test/voice-academy/wp-includes/werkgever.php",formdata, function(data){ //2
        //here you can do different action after make you post request //4
    });
    form.hide(); //3
}
```

The a-link, where I do the onClick, is also included in the script. The script is included right before the closing `</body>` tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">HERE</script>
```

Is it just a Syntax Error? Sorry for my newbie question... Doing my best to learn.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<form id="werkgever-form">
    First name:<br>
    <input type="text" name"first_name"><br>
    Last name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="lastname">
</form>
<a href="#" onClick="doSomething();">Send</a>
<body>
<script>
    (function($) {

        $(".em-booking-form").attr('id', 'werkgever-form');

        $('#masterclasses_repertoire').attr('placeholder','(max. 2000 tekens)');
        $('#masterclasses_biografie').attr('placeholder','(max. 2000 tekens)');
        $('#masterclasses_motivatie').attr('placeholder','(max. 2000 tekens)');
        $('#masterclasses_opmerkingen').attr('placeholder','(specifieke dieetbehoeften)');

        $(".em-attendee-fieldset").insertAfter($(".input-field-workshop_opmerkingen"));
        $(".em-attendee-fieldset").insertAfter($(".input-field-master_final_opmerkingen"));
        $(".em-attendee-fieldset").insertAfter($(".input-field-master_passief_opmerkingen"));

        $(".facturatiegegevens, .input-field-workshop_gelijk_adres, .input-field-factuur_bedrijf, .input-field-factuur_naam_contactpersoon, .input-field-factuur_email_contactpersoon, .input-field-factuur_straat, .input-field-factuur_nummer, .input-field-factuur_bus, .input-field-factuur_postcode, .input-field-factuur_gemeente, .input-field-factuur_land, .input-field-factuur_btw-nummer, .input-field-factuur_opmerkingen").wrapAll("<div class='kader'></div>");

        $(".postid-4465 .aanmelden").prop("value", "Aanmelden");

        $('input[value="Ik heb geen factuur nodig."]').attr('checked',true);



        $('.input-field-workshop_akkoord').after('<a id="werkgever-button" class="btn btn-primary" href="#" onClick="doSomething()">Reservering versturen</button>');

        $(".em-booking-gateway").css('display', 'block');

        $("input[name='workshop_wenst_u_een_factuur']").click(function () {
            $('.facturatiegegevens').css('display', ($(this).val() === 'Ik heb geen factuur nodig.') ? 'none':'block'),
                $('.kader').css('display', ($(this).val() === 'Ik heb geen factuur nodig.') ? 'none':'block'),
                $('.em-booking-gateway').css('display', ($(this).val() === 'Mijn werkgever zal betalen.') ? 'none':'block'),
                $('.em-booking-buttons').css('display', ($(this).val() === 'Mijn werkgever zal betalen.') ? 'none':'block'),
                $('#werkgever-button').css('display', ($(this).val() === 'Mijn werkgever zal betalen.') ? 'block' : 'none'),
                $('.input-field-workshop_gelijk_adres').css('display', ($(this).val() === 'Ik heb wel een factuur nodig.') ? 'block':'none'),
                $('.input-field-factuur_bedrijf').css('display', ($(this).val() === 'Ik heb geen factuur nodig.') ? 'none':'block'),
                $('.input-field-factuur_naam_contactpersoon').css('display', ($(this).val() === 'Ik heb geen factuur nodig.') ? 'none':'block'),
                $('.input-field-factuur_email_contactpersoon').css('display', ($(this).val() === 'Ik heb geen factuur nodig.') ? 'none':'block'),
                $('.input-field-factuur_straat').css('display', ($(this).val() === 'Ik heb geen factuur nodig.') ? 'none':'block'),
                $('.input-field-factuur_nummer').css('display', ($(this).val() === 'Ik heb geen factuur nodig.') ? 'none':'block'),
                $('.input-field-factuur_bus').css('display', ($(this).val() === 'Ik heb geen factuur nodig.') ? 'none':'block'),
                $('.input-field-factuur_postcode').css('display', ($(this).val() === 'Ik heb geen factuur nodig.') ? 'none':'block'),
                $('.input-field-factuur_gemeente').css('display', ($(this).val() === 'Ik heb geen factuur nodig.') ? 'none':'block'),
                $('.input-field-factuur_land').css('display', ($(this).val() === 'Ik heb geen factuur nodig.') ? 'none':'block'),
                $('.input-field-factuur_btw-nummer').css('display', ($(this).val() === 'Ik heb geen factuur nodig.') ? 'none':'block'),
                $('.input-field-factuur_opmerkingen').css('display', ($(this).val() === 'Ik heb geen factuur nodig.') ? 'none':'block');
        })

        $("#workshop_gelijk_adres").change(function() {
            if(this.checked) {
                //get the values of the filled fields
                $naam = $("#workshop_naam").val();
                $email = $("#user_email").val();
                $straat = $("#workshop_straat").val();
                $nummer = $("#workshop_nummer").val();
                $bus = $("#workshop_bus").val();
                $postcode = $("#workshop_postcode").val();
                $gemeente = $("#workshop_gemeente").val();
                $land = $("select.workshop_land").val();
                console.log("name");
                // then add those values to your billing infor window feilds

                $("#factuur_naam_contactpersoon").val($naam);
                $("#factuur_email_contactpersoon").val($email);
                $("#factuur_straat").val($straat);
                $("#factuur_nummer").val($nummer);
                $("#factuur_bus").val($bus);
                $("#factuur_postcode").val($postcode);
                $("#factuur_gemeente").val($gemeente);
                $("select.factuur_land").val($land);

                // then form will be automatically filled ..
            }
            else {
                $('#factuur_naam_contactpersoon').val('');
                $("#factuur_email_contactpersoon").val('');
                $("#factuur_straat").val('');
                $("#factuur_nummer").val('');
                $("#factuur_bus").val('');
                $("#factuur_postcode").val('');
                $("#factuur_gemeente").val('');
                $("select.factuur_land").val('');
            }
        })

    })(jQuery);

    function doSomething() {
        var form = $('#werkgever-form');
        var formdata = form.serialize();// 1
        $.post("http://www.lowie-design.be/test/voice-academy/wp-includes/werkgever.php",formdata, function(data){ //2
            //here you can do different action after make you post request //4
        });
        form.hide(); //3
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This code work at all. What difference from your code?

Comment: @PavloZhukov still got the error $ is not a function (doSomething and onclick)

Comment: You do query at the same hosting?